# How to save gapi response in php variable

Tags: php, api, google-analytics-api

I use GAPI (Google Analytics PHP Interface) to retrieve report about my site.
When I save the GAPI response in php variable I get an error.

The error I get:

```
Call to a member function getUsers() on array
```

When I run the request like this, I get the error:

```
//Get Total users who visited the site
$total_visitors=$this->gapi->requestReportData($this->config->item('ga_profile_id'), array('day'), array('users'), array('-day'), '', date('2008-01-01'), date('Y-m-d'), 1, 10000);

$data['total_visitors']  = $total_visitors->getUsers();
```

When I run the request like this, it works fine:

```
//Get Total users who visited the site
$this->gapi->requestReportData($this->config->item('ga_profile_id'), array('day'), array('users'), array('-day'), '', date('2008-01-01'), date('Y-m-d'), 1, 10000);

$data['total_visitors']  = $this->gapi->getUsers();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `requestReportData` is returning an array and not `$this` meaning the instance of the object that would allow you to call further methods (Like `getUsers()`) or manipulate the object. So either check the data in the array returned by `requestReportData` or you can try this if you really need to use the `getUsers()` method:

```
$this->gapi->requestReportData($this->config->item('ga_profile_id'), array('day'), array('users'), array('-day'), '', date('2008-01-01'), date('Y-m-d'), 1, 10000);
$total_visitors = $this->gapi->getUsers();
$data['total_visitors']  = $total_visitors->getUsers();
```